# How to match a word and sort by an order with a minimum in pouch db?

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

I am trying to create contacts app while trying to learn pouch db. I wish to sort queries by the `frequency` of contact. `frequency` is a simple integer that is incremented every time the person is contacted.

So far i have tried to build my view such as

```
by_frequency: function(doc){
   emit(doc.displayName.toLowerCase(), doc.frequency);
}
```

and then querying it by

```
{
   startkey: [query],
   endkey:   [query + '\uffff', {}],
   descending: true
}
```

But the answer is not what i need, infact its not even sorted by frequency

Is it possible to do something like

```
{
      startkey: [query, 1],
      endkey: [query + '\uffff', {}]
}
```

I also thought of getting all docs sorted by frequency with startkey: 1 and then filtering them for name but it just doesn't feels right ... or is it the only way to do this ?

In SQL It would be something like

`"SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE name LIKE "some%" order by frequency desc"`.

Comment: 2 cups of coffee in and I realized what am i doing, crap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to combine a prefix search with an integer search. But you can first do your prefix search and then sort in-memory:

```
by_frequency: function(doc){
   emit(doc.displayName.toLowerCase());
}
```

Then query with e.g.:

```
{
  startkey: "some",
  endkey: "some\uffff",
  include_docs: true
}
```

I feel obliged to add that even a SQL database will do this same thing. It just does it transparently under the hood, whereas in PouchDB/CouchDB, it's more explicit. Try doing an EXPLAIN on your query in MySQL and you'll see what I mean :)

Comment: Kind of what i thought, thanks :-) now i have 2 separate indexes one specifically for frequency and one specifically by name. I dislike having to load all items in memory though. wouldn't compound query by coverting the integer to a string be better ? something like `emit([doc.frequency, doc.displayName.toLowerCase()])`, what is wrong with that ?

Comment: PS I had nothing against Pouch I am refraining from doing in memory operations if they can be cached somehow, because i am targetting this for mobile devices where memory is a constraint so a query returning 194ms on a desktop chrome is probably going to be unusable on a low mobile.